# Creation of json object failed in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have an login page and main menu in my android application. In my login page user has to input appcode, username and email. three of these values have separate validations. 
After a successfull login to the system, if user clicks the back button user cannot go back to the login page. I added a `finish();`
in my login page for that.
And if user clicks on back button message box prompts and asks whether user needs to exit the app or not?

```
public void alertDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMenuActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Message")
            .setMessage("Do you want to exit the from app?")
            .setPositiveButton("YES",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @TargetApi(11)
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @TargetApi(11)
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).show();
}
```

If No user stays and if no user leaves the app and when restarts user need to reenter their details and proceed.

All of those functions are working except validation part.

If I enter invalid data to proceed app gives the error message and close the app.

Here is my logcat for that.

```html
09-01 10:39:56.541    8659-8659/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-01 10:39:57.001    8659-8674/com.NICT.nict D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-01 10:39:57.003    8659-8659/com.NICT.nict D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42b3e60, tid 8659
09-01 10:39:57.013    8659-8659/com.NICT.nict D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
09-01 10:39:57.048    8659-8674/com.NICT.nict D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42b3fe0, tid 8674
09-01 10:39:57.063    8659-8674/com.NICT.nict I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-01 10:39:57.083    8659-8674/com.NICT.nict D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-01 10:39:57.100    8659-8674/com.NICT.nict W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-01 10:39:57.100    8659-8674/com.NICT.nict W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb43a9700, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-01 10:40:03.606    8659-8659/com.NICT.nict W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-01 10:40:04.017    8659-8723/com.NICT.nict I/System.out﹕ http://demo.et.lk/nitcapi/api/login///
09-01 10:40:04.017    8659-8723/com.NICT.nict I/System.out﹕ Creation of json object failed
```

What should I do?

-Edit-
Validation codes,

```
loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!ServiceHandler.isOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
                MessageHandler.showMessage("No network connection",
                        getApplicationContext());
            }
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Looper.prepare();

                    String code = codeEdit.getText().toString();
                    String email = emailEdit.getText().toString();
                    String name = nameEdit.getText().toString();
                    if (code.length() == 0) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                MessageHandler.showMessage(
                                        "Please Enter the app code",
                                        getApplicationContext());
                                errorStatus = true;
                            }
                        });
                        ;
                    } else if (name.length() == 0) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                MessageHandler.showMessage(
                                        "Please Enter Your Name",
                                        getApplicationContext());
                                errorStatus = true;
                            }
                        });
                        ;
                    } else if (email.length() == 0) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                MessageHandler.showMessage(
                                        "Please Enter Your Email",
                                        getApplicationContext());
                                errorStatus = true;
                            }
                        });
                        ;
                    }

                    EmailValidator emailValidator = new EmailValidator();
                    if(!emailValidator.validate(email)){
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                MessageHandler.showMessage(
                                        "Invalid Email",
                                        getApplicationContext());
                                errorStatus = true;
                            }
                        });
                        ;
                    }
```

-Edit2 for  Diyoda -

```html
package com.NICT.nict.services;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ServiceHandler {

 static String response = null;
 public final static int GET = 1;
 public final static int POST = 2;

 public ServiceHandler() {

 }

 /**
  * Making service call
  * 
  * @url - url to make request
  * @method - http request method
  * */
 public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
  return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
 }

 /**
  * Making service call
  * 
  * @url - url to make request
  * @method - http request method
  * @params - http request params
  * */
 public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
   List<NameValuePair> params) {
  try {
   // http client
   DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
   HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

   // Checking http request method type
   if (method == POST) {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    // adding post params
    if (params != null) {
     httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    }

    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

   } else if (method == GET) {
    // appending params to url
    if (params != null) {
     String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
       .format(params, "utf-8");
     url += "?" + paramString;
    }
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

   }
   httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
   response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return response;

 }

 public static boolean isOnline(Context ctx) {
  ConnectivityManager cm;
  NetworkInfo info = null;
  try {
   cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
     .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return (info!=null&&!info.equals(null));
 }
}
```

edit 3 for  Diyoda

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:fillViewport="true"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="false" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/login_land_layout_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/codeEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/code"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:inputType="textPassword" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/name"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emailEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/login_land_margin_both"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/login_land_margin_both"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="#0f4b9b"
                    android:text="@string/login"
                    android:textColor="@color/LoginButtonColor" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poweredBy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/poweredby"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:scaleType="center"

            />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the logcat.

```html
09-01 14:16:17.792  27281-27281/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 15742K (120399), 50% free 18992K/37328K, paused 59ms, total 64ms
09-01 14:16:17.803  27281-27291/com.NICT.nict I/System.out﹕ [CDS]close[60594]
09-01 14:16:17.804  27281-27291/com.NICT.nict I/System.out﹕ close [socket][/0.0.0.0:60594]
09-01 14:16:17.805  27281-27291/com.NICT.nict I/System.out﹕ close [socket][/0.0.0.0:60594]
09-01 14:16:25.170  27281-27281/com.NICT.nict I/View﹕ Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Button{438bb780 VFED..C. ........ 0,30-440,78 #7f090022 app:id/loginBtn}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=190.54907, y[0]=23.447815, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=106787772, downTime=106787772, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
09-01 14:16:25.492  27281-27281/com.NICT.nict I/View﹕ Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{438bb780 VFED..C. ...P.... 0,30-440,78 #7f090022 app:id/loginBtn}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=190.54907, y[0]=23.447815, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=106788116, downTime=106787772, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
09-01 14:16:25.493  27281-27281/com.NICT.nict V/Provider/Settings﹕ get setting for user 0 by user 0 so skipping cache
09-01 14:16:25.493  27281-27281/com.NICT.nict V/Provider/Settings﹕ from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
09-01 14:16:25.499  27281-27281/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=128KB
09-01 14:16:25.499  27281-27281/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
09-01 14:16:25.500  27281-27281/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
09-01 14:16:25.500  27281-27281/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
09-01 14:16:25.500  27281-28060/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=17: interp stack at 0x55711000
09-01 14:16:25.500  27281-28060/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ init ref table
09-01 14:16:25.500  27281-28060/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ init mutex
09-01 14:16:25.500  27281-28060/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=17: created from interp
09-01 14:16:25.500  27281-27281/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
09-01 14:16:25.501  27281-28060/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=17: notify debugger
09-01 14:16:25.501  27281-28060/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=17 (Thread-1149): calling run()
09-01 14:16:25.514  27281-28060/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=17: exiting
09-01 14:16:25.514  27281-28060/com.NICT.nict D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=17: bye!
```

Comment: You should post those validation codes

Comment: Where's the validation code?

Comment: What are you using for validating json or creating json?

Comment: Added the validation code. Validation code worked properly before I added finish () and the dialog box. I added it because when I click back button app redirects to the login page. Is there anyway to prevent coming back to the login page without hurting my validations?

Comment: @ Diyoda I think u r looking for my service handler. So, I added that. but the thing is my validations are working without finish () and the dialog box. So, I think the error is the way i put those

Comment: As a stat one thing you can do is, instead of doing a finish() after successful login on Login activity, you can use             android:noHistory="true" on your login activity tag in Android Manifest

Comment: Problem solved by adding android:noHistory="true" but, If user enter login details for the first time user can enter to the main menu page. but, if user enter invalid details once and then try to enter correct details login button is not working.

Comment: @ Diyoda, added the login.xml too

Comment: @Manuli you still have not answered my question, is this causing an exception?, I think your issue has anything to do with Android Framework,  It is a business logic issue, Is your login button freezes in the second attempt?

Comment: I'm not getting any exception. button just freezes.

Comment: Not only second attempt. If Once app gives an error message afterwards button is not working. and when I restart the app and try to login with correct credentials it is working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the dialog box to the main menu.

```
  public void alertDialog() {
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMenuActivity.this)
        .setTitle("Message")
        .setMessage("Do you want to exit the from app?")
        .setPositiveButton("YES",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(11)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        finish();
                    }
                })
        .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(11)
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).show();
```

}